# Sitefinity account creation e-mail verification process

Tags: sitefinity

Does Sitefinity have a built-in process to deal with e-mail verification when creating user accounts?

Thanks
Jacques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that Sitefinity 4.x has such functionality. 
Under the widget section Users you will find Registration widget and Account activation widget.